# How to make a single HTML page to choose different CSS stylesheet for the theme by using dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, css, primefaces

HTML code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">        
<h:outputText value="Color:"></h:outputText>
<p:themeSwitcher effect="fade" style="width:165px" id="color">
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Green" itemValue="href='#{request.contextPath}/theme/primefaces-aristo/theme.css" />
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Blue" itemValue="href='#{request.contextPath}/theme/primefaces-aristo/theme1.css" />
</p:themeSwitcher>

</h:panelGrid>
```

I create 2 different CSS stylesheet which are theme.css and theme1.css

The problem is when I select the theme1.css(label as Blue), it doesn't work and the theme still the same.

How to solve it? Any ideas?

UPDATE:

JAVA page:

```
private String csspath = "";
private String selectedCss = "Pink";
private boolean trigger_valuechange_refresh;

public Test() {
    if(this.selectedCss.equals("Pink")) {
        this.csspath = "/theme/primefaces-aristo/theme1.css";
    } else {
        this.csspath = "/theme/primefaces-aristo/theme.css";
    }
} 

public String getCsspath() {
    return csspath;
} 

public String getSelectedCss(){
  return selectedCss;
}

public void setSelectedCss(String selectedCss){
  this.selectedCss = selectedCss;
}

 public void handleTest_combo_box_trans_groupValueChange() {
    this.trigger_changeValue_refresh = true;


if (this.trigger_changeValue_refresh) {
    if (_tg != null) {
        getTransactActivityType_ByLogCategory(_tg);
    }
    this.trigger_changeValue_refresh = false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="#{pc_Test.csspath}" value="#{pc_Test.csspath}" />

<p:selectOneMenu value="#{pc_Test.selectedCss}">
<p:ajax update="form1" listener="#{pc_Test.changeValue}"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Green" itemValue="Green" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Pink" itemValue="Pink" />
```

This is my updated code. I have some problem on JAVA page which is the value change part.
Any idea to solve it?

Comment: I think `<p:themeSwitcher>` is only working for default Primefaces themes.

Comment: Do you know about CSS switching? I want to do a CSS switching but I tried a lot of times and it doesn't work at all. But the theme switching work so I thought it will work on css switching as well. :( @QueryLars

Comment: The scope of your bean is ? Session or view ?

Comment: Don't forget to put your css file inside the WebContent/resources/css/ folder.

Comment: Yes. I put already.
The scope of my bean is Session. And I have edit my code on the question (changeValue part).

Comment: if you have put them in the right folder the path : "/theme/primefaces-aristo/theme1.css" is wrong. You should use "css/theme1.css" instead.

Comment: I tried. Still the same. @Lamq

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly i would use a managed bean in session scope for storing the user css choise.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "CSSManager")
@SessionScoped
public class CSSManager {
    private String csspath = "";
    private String selectedCss = "Blue";

    public CSSManager() {
        if(this.selectedCss.equals("Blue"))) {
            this.csspath = "css/theme1.css";
        } else {
            this.csspath = "css/theme.css";
        }
    } 

    public void changeValue(){

    }

    public String getCsspath() {
        return csspath;
    } 

    public String getSelectedCss(){
      return selectedCss;
    }

    public void setSelectedCss(String selectedCss){
      this.selectedCss = selectedCss;
    }
}
```

And inside your HTML code :

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="#{CSSManager.csspath}" value="#{CSSManager.csspath}" />
```

Don't forget to put your css file inside the WebContent/resources/css/ folder.

That should do the trick

Update :

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{CSSManager.selectedCss}">
    <p:ajax update="Your Main Form" listener="#{CSSManager.changeValue}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Blue" itemValue="Blue" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Green" itemValue="Green" /> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know how to put it into a dropdown list for user to choose which css they want. @Lamq

Comment: I just edited my post. Let me know if this answer fix your problem or not.

Comment: I updated my question. I have some problem on the JAVA page value change part. Any idea to solve it?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following approach:

You manage the selected CSS in a `ManagedBean` and let the user choose his oder her desired style with a `<p:selectOneMenu>`. So your xhtml page looks like this:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="#{myBean.stylesheet}" />

<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.stylesheet}">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="main" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Green" itemValue="theme.css" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Blue" itemValue="theme1.css" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

By using `<p:ajax>` you can trigger an update on whichever area (e.g. a surrounding `<h:form id="main">`) and apply the new styling. I don't know if `itemSelect` is the right event to listen to but you can find out by trying.

Your corresponding `ManagedBean` would look like the following:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {
    private String stylesheet;

    //getter and setter
}
```

This is only the approach I would take and therefore not tested. But this is a way it could work. Hope I could help you a little.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it doesn't work for me! I have update my question. Hope that you can take a look and give me some suggestion.Thanks